# Can I install SQL 2005 x86 developer on Windows 7 Professional

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-7, installation

Can I install SQL 2005 x86 developer on Windows 7 Professional

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I'm running it on Win7 right now with no problems.

Comment: did you also have to install SQL Server 2005 SP3 as it says upon start up of the setup process?

Comment: @uknown You should install the SP.  It should run without it but those SPs help.

Answer (score 0):

That is the whole purpose of the developer edition - it is the Enterprise version, but without the OS limitations built in, so you can install it on a non-server OS.

Comment: DO I need to install SSIS separately. I just install the developer edition but do not see SSIS installed? Suggestions please.

Comment: Yes. Integration Services, Analysis Services and Reporting Services are separate options within the same installer, when you run it only the database engine and its subcomponents (ie full text search) are selected by default. Just run the installer again, and modify your choices, it will install the extra bits you need.

Comment: got it. thanks. It is installed - just cant connect to the db - get an 18456 error upon connecting. Anyone seen this?